# Two cards side by side react native

Tags: react-native, flexbox

I referred to lot of places but still the issue persist, I've a card list here im displaying just four cards, now I want each row to have two cards each, but unable to do so. Here is the code for reference.

```
<View style={styles.panelBox}>
      <TouchableOpacity
      activeOpacity={1}
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('ExploreCareersIndex', { pathway_id: pathway.id })}
        style={[styles.card]}>
        <ImageBackground
          resizeMode='cover'
          style={styles.cardBody}
          imageStyle={styles.imageRadius}
          source={{uri: pathway.avatar_url}}>
        </ImageBackground>

        <Text style={styles.textImageStyle}>{pathway.name}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
```

and the CSS

```
panelBox: {
    paddingHorizontal: 15,
    paddingLeft: 10,
    paddingRight: 10,
    backgroundColor:'blue',
    flexDirection:'row',
    flexWrap:'wrap',
    flex:1,
    flexBasis:2,

  },
  card: {
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    width: "40%",
    height:130,
    textAlign: "center",
    backgroundColor:'red',
  },
  cardBody: {
    padding: 10,
    justifyContent: "space-between",
    overflow: "hidden",
    shadowColor: Colors.black,
    shadowOffset: {
      width: 0,
      height: 2,
    },
    shadowOpacity: 0.25,
    shadowRadius: 3.84,
    elevation: 5,
    height: 80,
  },
  imageRadius: {
    borderTopLeftRadius: 5,
    borderTopRightRadius: 5,
  },
  cardtitle: {
    textAlign: "left",
    fontSize: 12,
    lineHeight: 16,
    color: Colors.white,
    fontFamily: primaryFont.fontMedium,
    paddingRight: 10,
  },
  textImageStyle: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontSize: 12.5,
    fontFamily: primaryFont.fontMedium,
    marginTop: 5,
    color: Colors.gray4,
    height: '100%',
  },
```

still unsure why it isnt working. If you still need more reference I can provide some screenshot as well.
[image]

Comment: can you provide screenshot ?

Comment: @FeelRightz sure, just updating the answer

Comment: what you mean by two card each ?

Comment: So ATM, i've one card in each row even after providing width:40% to each, I want them to come two in a row .. you know, like side by side, so my row would have two cards each.

Comment: is my answer are what you looking for ?

Comment: @FeelRightz, it doesnt solves the issue to be honest. By two card in a row i meant was, i have 4 cards, they should be aligned 2 x 2. Currently its 4x1 sort of thing

Comment: updated answer, not sure i get correct or not, maybe you can draw a simple output image , post it here, more eazy to get what output you want

Answer (score 3):

Since you are trying to display a list of items try to use FlatList or SectionList. Using [numColumns](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist#numcolumns) Props in React Native FlatList you can easily display multiple columns layout.

Check below sample

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View, FlatList, StyleSheet, Text, Dimensions } from "react-native";

const ScreenWidth = Dimensions.get("window").width;

const DATA = [
  {
    id: "1",
    title: "1"
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    title: "2"
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    title: "3"
  }
];

export default class Example extends Component {
  renderItems = ({ item }) => (
    <View style={styles.item}>
      <Text style={styles.title}>{item.title}</Text>
    </View>
  );

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <FlatList
          data={DATA}
          renderItem={this.renderItems}
          keyExtractor={item => item.id}
          numColumns={2}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center"
  },
  item: {
    width: (ScreenWidth - 40) / 2 - 10,
    backgroundColor: "#000",
    padding: 10,
    marginVertical: 10,
    marginHorizontal: 10
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 32,
    color: "#fff",
    alignSelf: "center"
  }
});
```

If you have any doubts feel free to ask. Hope this will helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure is this what you want, two card in a row. So, in react-native you can just `flex:1` for parent, and set `width:'100%'` for child, and it will auto divided by two.

```css
.grandparent{
 display:flex;
 flex-direction:column;
}
.parent{
  display:flex; // in react-native just flex:1
}

.child{
  background-color:#333;
  height:100px;
  width:100%;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  text-align:center;
  color:#fff;
  font-size:30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grandparent">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child">1</div>
    <div class="child">2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child">3</div>
    <div class="child">4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add  ScrollView Insid the ScrollView add cards then in ScrollView add property  horizontal={true}